# Why are calcium deposits in chronic pancreatitis basophillic?

Tags: pancreatitis

In chronic pancreas, due to necrosis and inflammation the fats of peripancreatic fat undergo liquefactive necrosis and the released fatty acids react with Calcium which is released during necrosis and also partly from serum.

Now why does this stain basophillic?
Because if calcium even though it forms salt with fatty acid, the salt should be basic in nature, i.e. it'll react with acid and should be acidophillic.

Comment: it'll be a basic salt because calcium is a stronger base than fatty acids (weak acids)

Comment: okay, but if salt is formed between them won't that be basic

Comment: if we're talking about body then won't water be in surrounding and that would cause bascicity

Comment: yes that's what the point was, calcium soaps are formed in pancreatitis

Comment: Gotcha, thanks.